# foundation orbit slider stop

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, orbit

i am using foundation 5.4.5 and have a page with four working orbits. I'm trying to stop them from sliding automatically when the page is run. I've tried to change the settings in the foundation.orbit.js file (timer= false and timer_speed=0) and also tried to use in my script js file what suggested by foundation and by the answers here:

```
$(document).foundation('orbit', {
timer: false,    
timer_speed: 0
});
$(document).foundation();
```

Is there a bug in this version or am i missing something?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. Had a read through foundation forum and it seems to be a known issue. Orbit has been deprecated and probably won't be included in the next version so i moved to slick carousel as suggested on foundation's website. works great and takes 5 mins to implement

Answer (score 0):

Using data-attributes is the preferred method of making changes to our Javascript

```
<ul data-orbit data-options="timer:false;">
      ...
</ul>
```

`data-options="timer:false;"` will stop your slider sliding automatically.